# Exception using colon in XstreamAliasing

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xstream

I am getting a string as a response from server. I want to convert that string into java pojos using XStream. Some of my fields have colon in their name e.g. `@XStreamAlias(S:Envelope)`

During parsing, It shows the error "CannotResolveClassException:Envelope". But If I use

```
@XStreamAlias(Envelope)
```

It works fine.
How to tell Xstream to allow colon(":") in field name?

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me:

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAsAttribute;

import lombok.Data;


public class ColonAlias {

    @Test
    public void smokeTest() {
        InputStream file = ColonAlias.class.getResourceAsStream(ColonAlias.class.getSimpleName()+ ".xml");
        XStream xStream = new XStream();
        xStream.ignoreUnknownElements();
        xStream.processAnnotations(Parent.class);

        Parent parent = (Parent) xStream.fromXML(file);

        System.out.println(parent);
    }

    @XStreamAlias("parent")
    @Data
    public class Parent {

        @XStreamAsAttribute
        private String name;

        @XStreamAlias("p:age")
        private String age;
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent name="Adam">
        <p:age>33</p:age>
</parent>
```

Output:

```
ColonAlias.Parent(name=Adam, age=33)
```